# Why does xdebug not establish connection with NetBeans?

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I try using xdebug with NetBeans to debug PHP. I start debug, and NetBeans waits for ever for a connection with xdebug. I have NetBeans 6.8 (latest version) with the latest MAMP package installed on my mac.

My php.ini looks like this:

```
[xdebug]
;zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your php.ini really looks like what you posted, you have to un-comment the `zend_extension` line *(i.e. remove the '`;`' at its begninning)*, so Xdebug is actually loaded.

Then, make sure Xdebug is loaded, calling `phpinfo()` from a PHP file *(just to be sure)*.

After that : I suppose there should be some options to configure the debugger in netbeans ? If so, is netbeans listening on port 9000 ? (The one you configured in php.ini)

Comment: Must I restart all servers after changing php.ini? Did uncomment that, and checked NetBeans settings. Port 9000 is right. But NetBeans also mentions an Session ID: "netbeans-xdebug". Do I have to provide that somewhere in php.ini?

Comment: You'll have to at least restart Apache (modifications to php.ini are only taken into account when Apache starts) ; for the Session ID, there is a xdebug.idekey setting (see http://xdebug.org/docs/remote ) ; not sure it'll do the trick, but it might -- never remember having set, though ; I suppose the default value is fine with Eclipse PDT (I usually use eclipse PDT, and not netbeans)

Answer (score 10):

Finally, I had to add the idekey value like this:

```
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

now it works :-)

Comment: Note: I choose Pascal MARTIN's Answer as the accepted one, because without enabling xdebug by uncommenting it, my idekey thing would not do anything anyways ;-) (besides that I feel bad accepting my own answer so I just don't do it)

Comment: Thanks for your answer anyway : this can prove useful to others !

Comment: I hope it will :-) probably you were right, this idekey is by default fine for Eclipse.

Comment: Odd that you needed that. I've never had to put it in. Maybe it's a difference between the *nix and the Windoze (with which I am shackled) xdebug.

Comment: I didn't need this previously, but I've changed quite a bit on my Mac since then.. (homebrew PHP-FPM 5.3, upgrade to OS 10.8 and NB7.2)

Answer (score 6):

The following settings worked for me with NetBeans 7.2 on Mountain Lion after restarting Apache:

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart=on 
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

Comment: I also changed the project webroot `(right click on project > properties)` to `app/webroot/`, Not sure if this helped, but got it going for me! ;D

Answer (score 1):

Mac/MAMP users: If you have tried all of the above and it still doesn't work, reboot your Mac.  Restarting the servers through MAMP is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following with XAMPP 1.8.2 and NetBeans 7.4 with success.

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
```

Answer (score 0):

for me worked this way (thank you guys +1) /o/

```
<pre>
zend_extension = "c:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug2.dll"
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler"dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
</pre>
```

Config:
netbeans 7.3 - php 5.4 - xdebug 2.2 - xampp - win7(32bits)

Answer (score 0):

I've read that xdebug doesn't work with the version of PHP what ships with OS X.  I got it to work by updating php from version 5.4 to 5.5, using a handy package from php-osx.liip.ch, including precompiled xdebug extension.  Use this command:

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.5
```

Note that this will leave your default php installation intact, but disable it in httpd.conf.  Your new php.ini will be at "/usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini", with the xdebug config file at "/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-xdebug.ini".

Setup:
OS X version 10.9.2

Sources:
http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/upgrade-to-php-5-4-or-5-5-mac-osx-10-8-mountain-lion/