# xDebug seems OK installed, but not connecting with NetBeans

Tags: php, macos, netbeans, xdebug

I have now tried for hours getting xDebug (2.0.5 compiled from source) to work on my MacBook OS X with NetBeans 6.8. I have installed MAMP and am running a small PHP (5.2) test program with it, no problem. But when I try to debug I get this text in Netbeans: "Waiting for connection (netbeans-xdebug)" and nothing more happens. Netbeans is configured for Debugger Port 9000. No Zend Optimization in MAMP.

I have followed this: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-mac-os.html#installEnableXdebug
and http://www.xdebug.org/docs/install
and http://forums.netbeans.org/topic1513-0-asc-0.html etc

Here is part of my php.ini

```
[XDebug]

;zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/xdebug.so"

;[Zend]

;zend_optimizer.optimization_level=15

;zend_extension_manager.optimizer=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/zend/lib/Optimizer-3.3.9

;zend_optimizer.version=3.3.9

; Xdebug config for Mac OS X and NetBeans IDE

zend_extension=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/xdebug.so

xdebug.remote_enable=1

xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp

xdebug.remote_mode=req

xdebug.remote_host=localhost

xdebug.remote_port=9000

xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

I have read a lot of installation instructions etc and phpinfo show that xDebug is installed OK as V.5.2.11 (seen via "Open Start Page" in MAMP). However when i try in terminal PHP -m i do not see xdebug listed. I finally figured that PHP.INI is read from /etc so I copied the MAMP php.ini to php.ini there, thus added the xdebug.se, localhost, port 9000 etc info there. After that xdebug IS listed when I do PHP -m too, but I STILL get the NetBeans problem. Strange enough php -i shows version 5.2.10, not 5.2.11 as above!

I also tried this, adding the "netbeans-xdebug" for idekey: [Why does xdebug not establish connection with NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946643/why-does-xdebug-not-establish-connection-with-netbeans)

How come PHP_INFO() seemed to find my PHP.INI file under ../MAMP/... and not when doing PMP -m when it is read from /etc ?

How can I get PHP to always find the INI file under MAMP so I dont have to use two PHP.INI files to et PHPINFO() and PHP -m to work?

How can I resolve the NetBeans problem now that xDebug seems to be installed correctly but still not working in NetBeans? Something with this need for dual php.ini? Could I have compiled xdebug wrong, how to know? Something with php versions in xdebug / php? How to check?

Here is a part of the result from php -i:

```
xdebug

xdebug support => enabled
Version => 2.0.4

Supported protocols => Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol => $Revision: 1.125.2.6 $
GDB - GNU Debugger protocol => $Revision: 1.87 $
PHP3 - PHP 3 Debugger protocol => $Revision: 1.22 $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.idekey => pettermagnusson => netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.manual_url => http://www.php.net => http://www.php.net
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 100 => 100
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => 127.0.0.1 => 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log => /tmp/xdebug.log => /tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

Rgds
PM

Comment: To simplify the question a lot:

Can anyone think of  a reason that NeatBeans can not connect to xDebug when xDebug seems installed OK when checking with php_info() or php -i and php -m?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the wrong xDebug.so from Komodo and somehow also my own build was no good. Downloaded again and now its OK. Wow, this took me MANY hours, and no one could help either!
/PM

Answer (score 3):

```
How come PHP_INFO() seemed to find my PHP.INI file under ../MAMP/... and not when doing PMP -m when it is read from /etc ?
```

`phpinfo()` uses MAMP's PHP binary, while CLI uses your OS one.

```
How can I get PHP to always find the INI file under MAMP so I dont have to use two PHP.INI files to et PHPINFO() and PHP -m to work?
```

Leave the OS PHP untouched so you don't have problem upgrading and tweak the one bubled with MAMP as you need.

```
How can I resolve the NetBeans problem now that xDebug seems to be installed correctly but still not working in NetBeans? Something with this need for dual php.ini? Could I have compiled xdebug wrong, how to know? Something with php versions in xdebug / php? How to check?
```

Download the latest version of MAMP which includes xdebug extension compiled and add this to your `php.ini`.

```
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_log="/Applications/MAMP/logs/xdebug.log"
```

I use port 9001 as OSX doesn't seem to like the default.

Answer (score 0):

I checked and re-checked all the settings and setup instructions and still it appeared that XDebug didn't work. In the end I restarted my Mac and it magically started working. Maybe this will help someone in the same position as me.

Answer (score 0):

This is what working for me

`brew install php55-xdebug`

- grab the ini path, then paste the following to the last
  `php -i | grep 'Configuration File'`
  `vim /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini`
- add the following

  zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so"

  xdebug.default_enable=1
  xdebug.remote_enable=1
  xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
  xdebug.remote_host=localhost
  xdebug.remote_port=9001
  xdebug.remote_autostart=1