# Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug) OS X

Tags: php, macos, apache, netbeans, xdebug

After upgrading to php 5.4.16 and installing netbeans IDE 7.3.1 on my mac osx 10.8.4 Netbeans reports a 'waiting for connection (Netbeans - xdubug)' when initiating the debugging. I tried a few things as suggested on  [Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug) MAMP OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148855/waiting-for-connection-netbeans-xdebug-mamp-os-x) and [xDebug seems OK installed, but not connecting with NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002481/xdebug-seems-ok-installed-but-not-connecting-with-netbeans?rq=1), but nothing helped sofar. Having said that, I'm not very experienced with these kind of installations and the mac osx ;-(

Some more info:

I use Apache/2.2.22 and mysql.

I upgraded to php 5.4.16 using http://php-osx.liip.ch/. After that upgrade the php.ini file does not include xdebug info, but the 50-extension-xdebug.ini file does contain the following info:

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.default_enable=on
xdebug.remote_autostart=off
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.profiler_output_name=xdebug-profile-cachegrind.out-%H-%R
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 2048
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 128
```

Then I added:

```
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug 
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

..to this 50-extension-xdebug.ini file (as somewhere suggested in [xDebug seems OK installed, but not connecting with NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002481/xdebug-seems-ok-installed-but-not-connecting-with-netbeans?rq=1)).

I made another attempt by adding the contents of 50-extension-xdebug.ini to php.ini and restart the server, but no result.

The info box for xdebug shown by phpinfo() indicates xdebug is enabled and IDE Key is netbeans-xdebug. Then again, using the 'php -i | grep xdebug' terminal command doesnt show any result, so I'm not sure whether xdebug is actually enabled or not (?)

Any suggestions with respect to fixing the connection problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: UPDATE: works now after some more tweaking of php.ini...