# Xdebug Netbean in Windows 10 doesn't connect to remote host

Tags: xdebug

After upgrade to windows 10, Xdebug unable to connect to remote host. The log says:

```
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Remote address found, connecting to ::1:9001.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
```

The following is xdebug configuration:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = true
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.remote_log="D:/wamp/tmp/xdebug.log"
output_buffering=off
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0[/code]
```

I didn't forget to set Debugger port to 9001 in the Netbean options.

What did I miss?
regards

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563280/php-remote-debugging-xdebug-cant-connect-to-jetbrains-php-storm-client?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: I confirm the duplicate, issue is the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP remote debugging: XDebug can't connect to JetBrains php Storm client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563280/php-remote-debugging-xdebug-cant-connect-to-jetbrains-php-storm-client)