# Configuring Xdebug (PHP) path_mapping and php.ini for Sublime3

Tags: php, sublimetext3, xdebug

I'm trying to configure Xdebug to work with Sublime Text 3 but I can't get anything to show in the Context, Watch or Stack tabs e.g. by setting a breakpoint and clicking *Start Debugging (Launch Browser)*.  The browser opens the index.php file with `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=sublime.xdebug` appended to the url but execution of the code does not stop when the breakpoint is reached.

I've also tried adding `xdebug_break()` to index.php to no effect.

From what I've read, specifying `path_mapping` in the `.sublime-project` file seems the most likely solution.  The [documentation](https://github.com/martomo/SublimeTextXdebug#configuration) states that:

> **path_mapping**
>
> For remote debugging to resolve the file locations it is required to configure the path mapping with the server path as key and local path as value.

I'm using IIS on Windows 10 so the app's files are stored in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\` and the homepage's url is `http://localhost/index.php` which I'm assuming are the server path and local path respectively and as such the `.sublime-project` file looks like this:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "xdebug": {
            "url": "http://localhost/index.php",
            "path_mapping" : {"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\" : "http://localhost/index.php"}
        }
    }
}
```

Is this correct?  If it is, is my php.ini file configured correctly?

```
[ExtensionList]
.
.
.
zend_extension = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php-5.6.30-nts-Win32-VC11-x86\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.1-5.6-vc11-nts.dll"

[XDEBUG]
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
```

Comment: *"which I'm assuming are the server path and local path respectively"* NO -- it has nothing to do with URL. Path mappings needs to be used when remote **file path** does not match local one, e.g. on local computer website's `index.php` is located in `/var/www/` but on remote it's in `/var/www/html/site-name/`. Collect xdebug logs to see what's happening.

Comment: Thank you kindly @LazyOne problem now solved with the help of your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `path_mapping` and *php.ini* settings were both incorrect.

Based on @LazyOne's comment, removed the incorrect `path_mapping` in the `.sublime-project` file so it now looks like this:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "xdebug": {
            "url": "http://localhost/index.php"
        }
    }
}
```

Then added `xdebug.remote_log="C:\Windows\Temp\Xdebug\remote.log"` to *php.ini* and inspecting the log showed:

```
I: Remote address found, connecting to ::1:9000.
E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(
```

Searching this error lead to @Axel's answer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563280/php-remote-debugging-xdebug-cant-connect-to-jetbrains-php-storm-client) and based on this, changed `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` to `xdebug.remote_connect_back=0` in *php.ini*

Breakpoints then started working and the *Context*, *Watch* and *Stack* tabs started showing the relevant data on reaching them.

Comment: So the issue was that xdebug support in Sublime does not support IPv6 .. so it must be IPv4? How does the successful session looks in the xdebug log? I mean -- what IP:port it is able to connect to?

Comment: `localhost:9000` log shows `I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000.` then `I: Connected to client. :-)`