# PHPStorm unable to make external connection with xdebug

Tags: ide, xdebug, phpstorm

My OS is Mac Mountain lion.

My PhpStorm version is 5.0.4.

Here is my php xdebug info:

- xdebug.remote_autostart => Off => Off
- xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off => Off
- xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
- xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
- xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
- xdebug.remote_host => 127.0.0.1 => 127.0.0.1
- xdebug.remote_log => data/logs/xdebug.log => data/logs/xdebug.log
- xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
- xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
- xdebug.idekey => no value => no value

I can debug PhpScript Run Type in PhpStorm,It works fine.So I think xdebug configure well.

But after I try follow the "Zero Configure Debug"(Which with Webapplication Run Type),Phpstorm can not connect with the incoming connection.

Here is my step:

1. Click Start Listion Php Connection.(Toggle the call to green)
2. Click Run->Break at first line in PhpScript,and set breakpoint at first statement.
3. Choose My WebApplication Config and click Debug button.Then it launches chrome and link to my phpscript.(with ?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=19869)
4. In PhpStorm,Debugger shows Waiting for incoming connection with ide key '19869'.
5. In termial,print`lsof -i4TCP:9000`.

   > COMMAND PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME 
   >   webide  288 wangfeng   69u  IPv6 0xa83881cdce30c579      0t0  TCP *:cslistener (LISTEN)
6. Open Chrome's Developer Tool,Select Cookies.

   > XDEBUG_SESSION 19869 localhost / Wed, 30 Jan 2013 05:27:17 GMT 19
7. Refresh Chrome.Not able connect with PhpStorm debug connection.

Additional:

- My firewall was closed.
- My Server is nginx.My phpwebapp and server is all at my local machine.

Does it cause ipv6?

Hopes help!I have try everything,extensions bookmarklets,not work at all.

Comment: Enabling [xdebug.remote_log](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log) can provide you more details.

Comment: Yes,I have set it.But nothing logged.

Comment: `data/logs/xdebug.log` -- I'm not a Mac user, so just a suggestion: 1) use **full** path (from the root) 2) make sure it is writtable. But most likely the issue is that xdebug does not work with IPv6 -- **you will need IPv4**

Comment: 1)My path has set to full.2)I have made it with full permision.3)How can I config that?Please tell me,thank you very much!

Comment: As I have mentioned already "I'm not a Mac user" and  therefore I do not know the solution straight away. Do you want me to google it for you? **P.S.** I definitely can confirm that **xdebug needs TCP v4 and not v6** -- it stated by xdebug author few times, the most recent mentioning I managed to find was made less than 1 year ago.

Comment: Today I try debug,it works.Nothing change made.I don't know why,may be about the start step.Thank you all the same.

Comment: i have same problem what can i do till now i did not get proper solution

Comment: Same issue i found... tried with ALL SOLUTIONS but couldn't find anything that works for me.

Answer (score 14):

It's possible that port 9000 is being used by some other process.

1. In php.ini set `xdebug.remote_port=9001` or another unused port of your choosing.
2. In PHPStorm go to Settings->PHP->Debug and under the Xdebug section set Debug port to 9001.
3. Restart your web server.
4. Start debugging.

Comment: @jerson no worries. It was a pain when I came across the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

After checking all the configuration in php.ini file and the IDE, do not forget to add the browser-specific extension that basically communicates via the IDE via IDE Key.

Please refer to this [link](http://blog.zipleen.com/2014/03/debugging-php-with-xdebug-with-phpstorm.html)