# xDebug doesn't get fired, but PhpStorm does detect the incoming connection

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, homestead

When I launch Xdebug through a browser using an extension (like The easiest Xdebug for Firefox and Xdebug Helper in Chrome), PhpStorm will receive the incoming connection, but it will not start the debugger when I click accept.

[The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596923/phpstorm-unable-to-make-external-connection-with-xdebug?rq=1) didn't do the trick for me. Since I use Homestead, I know fpm uses port 9000. Putting the xdebug port to 10000 didn't help.

My Xdebug settings are:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 10000
xdebug.scream=0
xdebug.cli_color=1
xdebug.show_local_vars=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

And all the server mappings are pointing to the correct directory on the homestead server.

**[Edit]**

By request, I went to check my phpinfo. I ran `php -i | grep xdebug`, this it the output:

```
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini,
xdebug
xdebug support => enabled
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 1 => 1
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 100 => 100
xdebug.overload_var_dump => On => On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back => On => On
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => localhost => localhost
xdebug.remote_log => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => On => On
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

**[Edit 2]**

I added the information of Xdebug which comes from my `phpinfo()`

```
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    1   1
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    On  On
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level    100 100
xdebug.overload_var_dump    On  On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart Off Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back  On  On
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    On  On
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.remote_log   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  On  On
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

**[Edit 3]**

I tried to change the xdebug port to 10000 since fpm uses port 9000, reflecting that change in PhpStorm. It originally fired the debugger and complained that the HandleExceptions.php file could not be mapped. So I mapped it manually. After doing so, the debugger didn't fire anymore.

Comment: Please show: xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output (must be obtained in a same way as you run your script -- i.e. via browser in your case); Also -- xdebug log: http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log

Comment: @LazyOne I'll need to so that tomorrow morning. I'm not on that computer now.

Comment: Well, xdebug settings seems to be OK, although they were not taken in a way that was requested (Mac/Linux may use different php.ini files for CLI and web server hence the way you took them may not provide actual values). In any case: what xdebug log says? Is it definitely tries to connect to 80 port ...?

Comment: @LazyOne I added the new relevant information.

Comment: I was running through similar issue. I have added `xdebug.remote_enable = true` after zend_extension and it's now working. Maybe substituting 1 in your configuration by true might help.