# xDebug times out the connection

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, phpstorm, xdebug, putty

I have an website running on an AWS EC2 instance. This is a Magento store, i.e. a PHP-application running in a LAMP stack. I have a weird caching issue, which I'm not able to reproduce locally, so I cloned the live instance and trying to debug the issue with xDebug. Here is my xDebug config:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 500
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "/tmp/xdebug"
;;xdebug.remote_connect_back = On
xdebug.remote_autostart=On
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = "PHPStorm"
```

I also setup a Putty SSH tunnel like this
[image: putty tunnel config]

and setup my PHPStorm to listen for xDebug connections.
I managed to receive a connection and started debugging, but then, out of sudden PHPStorm "hanged": it was still thinking that it is connected but was not able to show the current place in the code and all execution control buttons became inactive.

Any further attempts to connect seem to fail.
If I disable the xDebug and restart the Apache - site loads fine. 
If I enable the xDebug and restart Apache - site loads forever never loading the page.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Tried in two browsers: Chrome and Firefox - same result.
The site is working over SSL.

**UPDATE2**
Tried switching to port 9001 - same thing, credit goes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596923/phpstorm-unable-to-make-external-connection-with-xdebug?rq=1)

Comment: First -- disable `xdebug.remote_autostart` and try invoking debugging sessions manually (CLI .. or GET/POST parameters; cookie .. or even by putting `xdebug_break();` in your code instead of actual breakpoint). 2) Try restarting IDE (or even whole computer) 3) Check xdebug log (`xdebug.remote_log`) -- it may give you useful info.

Comment: @LazyOne looks like your approach helped, I pressed "Debug" button in PHPStorm and it sort of worked, I'm now in debugging process, thanks to `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=16642` in the URL. I was not doing that before since site is on SSL and phpstorm does not allow to configure debug URLs as SSL ones. Can't really tell how it worked :(