# How do I get Netbeans and Xdebug to work with NginX

Tags: php, nginx, netbeans, xdebug

I have an Ubuntu 16.10 laptop that I use for testing websites that I develop, and I recently switched from Apache2 to NginX. I use Netbeans and Xdebug to debug my PHP scripts.

Instructions for setting up Xdebug with NginX seemed pretty straightforward. Simply put the following lines in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini`:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_connect_back=On
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug.log
```

... then restart NginX with `sudo service nginx restart`. But this doesn't work.

I checked for answers on Stack Overflow, and I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18579535/184108), which says I need to put the following code in a configuration file, but, it seems to be specific to PHP 5 and I am running PHP 7.0, and also it only refers to an NginX configuration file without specifying which one, so I don't know exactly where to put it.

```
location / {
        root /var/www/bresson/web/;
        include fastcgi_params;     
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/dispatch.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
```

**How do I connect Xdebug to NginX so that I can debug PHP with Netbeans?**

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer [here](https://gist.github.com/hollodotme/418e9b7c6ebc358e7fda).

It says to get something called "redis", though I'm not totally sure that's necessary:

```
apt-get install php-redis
```

In any case, I did that. The next step was to run this command:

All the manual compiling instructions can be ignored, because everything needed is now in the repositories. I already had Xdebug, NginX, and everything installed. So I skipped to this line:

```
sudo echo "zend_extension=xdebug.so" > /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini
```

But, long story short, I found through trial and error that this wasn't enough. Instead, I had to open it and add the following:

```
zend_extension = xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_children = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
```

After that, I ran these commands:

```
ln -sf /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
ln -sf /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
service php7.0-fpm restart
```

Check results by running `php -m | grep -i xdebug`, which should return:

```
xdebug
Xdebug
```

I then restarted everything, though this may not be necessary:

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
sudo service nginx restart
```

I then tested it by debugging a site in NetBeans, and it worked!

**Addendum:**

I kept getting an `503 Bad Gateway` error when debugging my local sites. It seemed the problem was that the Xdebug connection was timing out. The solution seems to be to go the configuration file for the site you're debugging, for example `/etc/nginx/sites-available/local_example.conf` and you want to add a parameter called `fastcgi_read_timeout` to the PHP section. For example, this is what it looks like now in my site `conf` files:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
}
```

I set it to `fastcgi_read_timeout 600;` so that I'd have 10 minutes to sit around and think about what I'm doing while hanging on a breakpoint. I looked for a more global setting, but couldn't find it, so this is the solution that's working for me now.